# LG Gram install Ubuntu with USB

Tags: ubuntu, usb, bootable-media, secure-boot

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18 LTS on an LG Gram 17 laptop. I created a bootable USB with the Ubuntu 18 image. I disabled already secure boot and also removed signatures (I think it is called setup mode). And the problem is that I'm always getting the same result, unable to install Ubuntu:

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\NULL - Not found
Failed to load \EFI\BOOT\NULL: Not found 
start_image() returned Not Found
```

I've tried many different ways to generate the image, from Windows 10, from Ubuntu 18 itself, using different images... hence I don't think that is the problem. I think it is a configuration on my computer, but I not able to fix this issue even searching these specific strings.

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: When exactly are you getting these messages? How are you preparing the bootable USB?

Comment: @Beto Aveiga Installation, as per Canonical, Ubuntu's publishers, is typically done following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 . Once you make a LiveUSB, install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0.

Comment: @gronostaj I'm creating the USB with Rufus. I downloaded the ISO from the Ubuntu site, the 18 LTS and also the Budgie. Both boot images worked at some point, with specific BIOS config (disabling secure Boot and other stuff) but they aren't working now.

Comment: @gronostaj last bootable USB with Budgie worked although I chose "try Ubuntu", but then due to an ACPI error, I wasn't able to even try it, my laptop was freeze. Then I reboot, without any BIOS change, not a single change, but the USB stopped working.

Comment: I'm having the same problem trying to install from a usb stick - the splash screen shows those three error lines lines in the upper corner and then boots into windows. How did you get past it?

Comment: @BetoAveiga what was the "other stuff" you did to get the pc to boot from usb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that my bootable USB only worked right after I saved the UEFI configuration. If restarted my machine, then the bootable usb was not able to boot, not even after power off.

I also had disabled secure boot and legacy OS support turned on. I'm not sure if those two options are required to be able to boot with a USB, although based on what I've read disable secure boot is necessary.

Also, to avoid issues when installing Ubuntu consider do the following before:
https://github.com/crazyluv/solve-lg-gram-17-linux-boot-error

Good luck!

Comment: I've tried everything listed here. Do you have any other tips? I'm not sure what the difference is, but I have the 14" version.

Comment: Try to disable something like BIOS guard, or Boot guard, which is in the advanced options on your EUFI/BIOS menu. To access advanced options do Ctrl+F7 once you are on your BIOS/UEFI screen. Hope that helps. I struggled installing Ubuntu so let know how everything went for you.

Comment: I'm not sure what the fix was, but I did get it working. I tested the USB on my desktop and was able to boot, but I went ahead and reloaded Ubuntu to it. I also went through the Windows 10 setup and let it run through all updates.

After that it loaded fine (I nuked Windows during this). The only option I changed in the BIOS was disabling secure boot.

Now everything runs like a dream and I'm loving this laptop!

Comment: Glad it worked whatever it was! :) What I noticed was that USB boot only worked right after saving UEFI settings.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you got past that point but are now hitting acpi errors. According to [this gist](https://github.com/crazyluv/solve-lg-gram-17-linux-boot-error) you can get past those errors by disabling Thunderbolt RTD3 in the BIOS.

Comment: Thanks! I read that before and was able to install Ubuntu, I have to change a few things on UEFI advanced settings, but now I'm not able to boot from Ubuntu. I created a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in 17z990 following aust1n proposal.

a) Enter BIOS/UEFI.
b) Go to Advanced.
c) Ctr+Alt+F7 to really activate Advande options.
d) Go to SW Guard Extensions (SGX) and move from Enabled to Disabled.

Save and voila... the USB stick runs.

A couple of unimpotant points (I guess).
a) The flash drive I did was made through dd (sudo dd if= of=/dev/sdb (TAKE CARE YOU CHOOSE THE CORRECT ONE). This way it is functional but in some cases the USB Pen is hard to move back to standard Vfat/Fat32 partitioning.
b) At this last attempt I moved the usb pen from the right side usb to the left side. I don't think it has anything to do with the solution of the problem, yet...